# Handling ListenableFuture in Project reactor

Tags: project-reactor

I've started playing with project reactor and wanted to move one of our API to reactive way of doing things. I was wondering what is right away of handling things like ListenableFuture.

In my case, I'm using Cassandra and when I call `session.executeAsync()` this returns back a ResultSetFuture which extends ListenableFuture.
Below is the example of what I have coded for now and I don't seem to be happy with exposing ListenableFuture to clients.

```java
public Mono<ListenableFuture<Void>> save(Publisher<AccountDTO> accountPublisher) {
    return Mono.just(accountPublisher)
            .map(accountDTO -> {
                Account accountEntity = modelMapper.map(accountDTO, Account.class);
                return mappingManager.mapper(Account.class).saveAsync(accountEntity);
            })
            .retry(1)
            .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Unable to create account "))
            .mapError(throwable -> new MyCustomException(""));
}
```

My question is:

> Is it a good practice to expose ListenableFuture, I personally don't want to give anything like this back to the client where they can block. Is there a better way to handle this in project reactor where I can just return a Mono?

Answer (score 7):

You can easily bridge a `ListenableFuture<Void>` async API to instead expose a `Mono<Void>`, by using the `Mono.create()` factory method. The method takes a `Consumer<Sink>`, which you provide as a lambda that:

1. add a success listener to the future which calls `sink.success()` (since there is no actual value, or you can also call `success(aVoid)` with the `Void` value received by the listener)
2. add a failure listener to the future which calls `sink.error(failure)`

That's pretty much it! See the reference documentation on `create` (although this one mentions the `Flux` version which is a little bit more complex due to having to handle multiple values): http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#producing.create

Comment: Thanks @Simon for guiding me on this. That helped.

Answer (score 5):

Posting code snippet that I coded as guided by @Simon above.

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> save(AccountDTO accountDTO) {
    return Mono.create(voidMonoSink -> {

        Account account = converter.map(accountDTO, Account.class);

        ListenableFuture<Void> voidListenableFuture = mappingManager.mapper(Account.class).saveAsync(account);

        Futures.addCallback(voidListenableFuture, new FutureCallback<Void>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                voidMonoSink.success(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                log.error("Unable to save account " + accountDTO, t);
                voidMonoSink.error(new MyCustomException());
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this post is quite old the APIs for both libraries have matured yielding a simpler solution.

One can simply use [default CompletableFuture completable()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html#completable--) in conjunction with [public static  Mono fromFuture(CompletableFuture<? extends T> future)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromFuture-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture-).

Here is an example adapted from [Spring for Apache Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#examples)

```
public void sendToKafka(final MyOutputData data) {
  final ProducerRecord<String, String> record = createRecord(data);

  CompletableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>> future = template.send(record).completable();
  
  Mono<SendResult<Integer, String>> mono = Mono.fromFuture(future)
    .doOnSuccess((result) ->  handleSuccess(data))
    .doOnError((ex) -> handleFailure(data, record, ex))
    .doFinally((signalType) -> { if(signalType == SignalType.CANCEL) future.cancel(true); });
  
  mono.subscribe();
}
```

[Note from Reactor JavaDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html#completable--)

> Note that the future is not cancelled when that Mono is cancelled, but that behavior can be obtained by using a [doFinally(Consumer)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doFinally-java.util.function.Consumer-) that checks for a [SignalType.CANCEL](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/SignalType.html#CANCEL) and calls [CompletableFuture.cancel(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html?is-external=true#cancel-boolean-).

Comment: While I don't know about dependencies mentioned in this question, in my case `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture` does not provide any method to convert ListenableFuture to CompletableFuture (and I cant change that since it comes from 3rd party library). So it might happen that only @Nishant and @Bharath solution's will work.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 using lambdas, if you are looking for an implementation to Simon's answer for creating Flux using ListenableFutures,

```
Flux.create(fluxSink -> {
            future.addCallback(
                    result -> {
                        fluxSink.next(result);
                        fluxSink.complete();
                    },
                    ex -> fluxSink.error(ex));
        });
```